# Where can I find libsmi 64bit for windows?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, snmp, wireshark

As part of porting an old C++ 32 bit project to a 64 bit project, I find it difficult to track down [libsmi](http://www.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/projects/libsmi/download.html?lang=de) binaries for 64 bit windows development. Now I'm reluctant to port that project to 64 bit myself, compiling is less of the issue. I do see that there are some definition for 64 bit int in the 32 bit project.

1. Is the 64 bit types is what they mean by 64 bit windows support?
2. While researching the issue, it seems that the Wireshark community encountered this issue [before](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/878/cant-enable-snmp-decodes-in-64-bit-windows). Can anyone from that community share some info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but I found this in the wireshark SVN, (via the wireshark [Wiki page on Win64](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/Win64)) http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc?view=revision&root=Wireshark-win64-libs&revision=317

The [ZIP file](http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc/trunk/packages/libsmi-svn-40773-win64ws.zip?view=co&revision=317&root=Wireshark-win64-libs&pathrev=317) appears to contain the binaries. I have not tested these.

Comment: from the readme file -  "Compiled using mingw on Ubuntu" Mini Gnu for windows on Ubuntu ? I Don't get it.

Comment: Yes, cross compiled from an Ubuntu host, for a windows target, using the mingw compiler.